# ReactJS onClick in function returned JSX not detected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Inside of my render I have a function that returns a block of JSX:

```
function userBlock(category) {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12 pb15">
                <Chip icon={ category } name={ category }/>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-12 pb15">
                <div className="well">
                    <p className="lead text-center">You have not yet created any lists.</p>
                    <p className="text-center">
                        <a onClick={ createNewList }><i className="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> New List</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Currently that `createNewList` function does not fire, at first I tried using `this.createNewList` and I also binded that to the constructor function. However that threw an error...

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'createNewList' of undefined

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        category: props.category,
        category_cards: []
    };
    this.createNewList = this.createNewList.bind(this);
}

createNewList() {
    console.log('1 createNewList');
}

render() {

    function createNewList() {
        console.log('2 createNewList');
    }
```

#### Full code

---

```
import React from 'react';
import Chip from '../Chip';

export class List extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            category: props.category,
            category_cards: []
        };
        this.createNewList = this.createNewList.bind(this);
    }

    createNewList() {
        console.log('1 createNewList');
    }

    render() {

        function createNewList() {
            console.log('2 createNewList');
        }

        function defaultBlock(category) {
            // return <Categories category={ category }/>
            return <h1>Categories component goes here</h1>
        }

        function userBlock(category) {
            return (
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12 pb15">
                        <Chip icon={ category } name={ category }/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12 pb15">
                        <div className="well">
                            <p className="lead text-center">You have not yet created any lists.</p>
                            <p className="text-center">
                                <a onClick={ createNewList }><i className="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> New List</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }

        function toggler(category) {
            return category === 'user' ? userBlock(category) : defaultBlock(category);
        }

        return (
            <div className="container">
                { toggler(this.state.category) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default List;
```

Comment: Should be `this.createNewList`

Comment: @DaveNewton I did that and posted the error I got, found out from the answer below that I needed to move all the functions out of the render to become methods of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scoping issue, define all the `function` inside the class (outside of render method) and call them by `this.functionName()`.

Use this, check the working code:

```js
class List extends React.Component {
    
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                category: props.category,
                category_cards: []
            };
            this.createNewList = this.createNewList.bind(this);
        }
    
        createNewList() {
            console.log('2 createNewList');
        }
    
        defaultBlock(category) {
            return <h1>Categories component goes here</h1>
        }
    
        userBlock(category) {
            return (
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12 pb15">
                        <Chip icon={ category } name={ category }/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-12 pb15">
                        <div className="well">
                            <p className="lead text-center">You have not yet created any lists.</p>
                            <p className="text-center">
                                <a onClick={ this.createNewList }><i className="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> New List</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    
         toggler(category) {
            return category === 'user' ? this.userBlock(category) : this.defaultBlock(category);
        }
    
        render() {        
    
            return (
                <div className="container">
                    { this.toggler(this.state.category) }
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

ReactDOM.render(<List/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Thanks! And great explanation and example :)

Comment: glad, it helped you :)